# svn commit error minimum number of learners not available

Tags: svn, commit

the commit error message is :

> minimum number of learners not available

how to solve this problem? I tried svn clean up, and update again
but i couldn't solve. can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

"Learners" seems to be a term within WANdisco's Subversion server software:

https://docs.wandisco.com/svn/archive/ms-plus1.3/reference.html

Please check with your server administrator if there is a configuration or runtime error with your Subversion server.